# Rearrange comments in macOS Pages

Tags: pages

After rearranging a macOS Pages document, the comments now point to deleted sections.

However the information from those sections is now available elsewhere and the comments still apply.

Is there any way I can attach an existing comment to a new paragraph in the now rewritten text?

This is a work document and ideally I would keep not only the comment text but also author information. (Otherwise I can just copy-paste the comment content).